# I have two ubuntu OSes and am going to install WIndows 7. What will go wrong and how do i fix it?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I have ubuntu8 and ubuntu10 on my system, and want to also install windows 7. i have read that i need to first install windows and then ubuntu etc, but i currently have ubuntu first. once i install windows, i think it will mess up with grub. How will i access ubuntu after i install windows and fix everything that might be broken? and exactly what will be broken?

Answer (score 2):

Windows will replace the grub bootloader with the ntldr bootloader, which doesn't understand linux. You'll need to re-install grub as your bootloader and configure it to see each OS. I would back up your grub config before-hand and then add Windows.

Well, actually I'd just run a VM under ubuntu... but up to you.